# Distributing $8$ different articles among $7$ boys

Tags: combinatorics

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> Find the number of ways in which $8$ different articles can be distributed among $7$ boys, if each boy is to receive at least one article.

---

**Attempt at a solution:-**

First, start by numbering the boys from $1$ to $7$, which can be done in $7!$ ways.

After the boys have been numbered then we resume our task of distributing the articles to the boys. As, each boy is supposed to at least get a single article.

Hence,

$\text{Ways of giving $1$ article to the $1^{\text{st}}$ boy= $8\choose1$}\\
\text{Ways of giving $1$ article to the $2^{\text{nd}}$ boy= $7\choose1$}\\
\text{Ways of giving $1$ article to the $3^{\text{rd}}$ boy= $6\choose1$}\\
\vdots\\
\text{Ways of giving $1$ article to the $7^{\text{th}}$ (and the last) boy= $2\choose1$}$

Now remains the last article, which can go to any one boy of the $7$ boys in ${{7}\choose{1}}=7$ ways

So, the number of ways of distributing $8$ articles among $7$ boys$=$

$$7!\times \left( \binom{8}{1} \times \binom{7}{1} \times \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{1}\right)\times \binom{7}{1}$$

But, the arrangement of the two things that the $1^{\text{st}}$ boy gets is of no relevance so we gotta remove the consideration of the two objects being permuted among themselves.

Hence, the total the number of ways of distributing $8$ articles among $7$ boys$=$

$$\frac{7!\times \left( \binom{8}{1} \times \binom{7}{1} \times \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{1}\right)\times \binom{7}{1}}{2!}$$

The textbook gives the answer to the question as 
$$7\times \left( \binom{8}{2} \times \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{1}{1}\right)$$

Where am I going wrong

Comment: But they are not asking about the arrangements, so there is no need of a $2!$ here.

Comment: @Rohan-Yes, you are indeed right that the arrangement(or the order in which the two articles are received by the 1st boy) of the articles makes no difference, hence I divided the whole expression $$7!\times \left( \binom{8}{1} \times \binom{7}{1} \times \binom{6}{1} \times \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{3}{1} \times \binom{2}{1}\right)\times \binom{7}{1}$$ by $2!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem here is that you have ordered the boys and also regarded the distribution of the presents as extra options.

Probably the simplest way to get to the answer is to select one boy to get two presents ($7$ options), he chooses those two ($\binom 82$) then each boy chooses in turn ($6!$ options) :
$$7\binom 82 \binom 61 \binom 51 \binom 41 \binom 31 \binom 21 \binom 11 = 7\binom 82 6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1 = 7!\binom 82 $$

Another way to view the last formulation is that you pick two presents to "bundle", then distribute the 7 packages to the 7 boys.

Comment: So what you are pointing out is that it is only necessary to chose the boy who gets two articles but not others as they are anyways going to get only one present. So for the other boys who do not get two articles, only permuting the $7$ gifts is needed. Is my line of thought correct?

Comment: Yes, effectively you can think that by counting options for ordering the boys **and** the presents, any boy-to-present-matching will happen many ways.

Answer (score 3):

You have permuted both the boys and the articles, which is incorrect.

I'd prefer to work it out as

[ Choose "lucky" boy ] $\times$ [ Permute articles ]

$= \dbinom71 \times \dfrac{8!}{2!1!1!1!1!1!1!}$

which, of course, could be abbreviated as $  7\times \dfrac{8!}{2!}$

**PS:**
On closer scrutiny, I find that the book answer you give is also incorrect !